# Visual Studio Android Emulator won't start throws unhandled null exception

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I've just installed Win 10 and VS2015 pro.  Trying to use the new Visual Studio Android Emulator, but it refuses to start. It doesn't show up as a target in VS, and clicking the menu item: tools/Visual Studio Emulator for Android... does nothing.

I ran the Windows Phone emulator as a sanity check and it works fine.

Trying to run the Android Emulator from the command line logs the following unhanded exception in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: emulatormgr.exe, version: 1.0.50715.4, time stamp: 0x55a72dc4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3b2a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000b3e28
Faulting process id: 0x1290
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0dbe170d92746
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\emulatormgr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 60cfdb18-3660-49db-9a91-b19f18222495
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by an updated version of the emulator. I can now successfully run it.